# Linear programming: Logic condition

Tags: linear-programming

I have a problem in writing a constraint in linear programming.
I have a boolean variable c, that variable has to be 1 only if another variable (let's say x) is (for example) 5.

x is a non-negative integer.

I did:

c <= x / 5

c <= 5 / x

Unfortunately, in this way the model become non-linear.
Is there a way to express that condition in a linear way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general something like:

```
5 - M(1-c) <= x <= 5 + M(1-c)
5.001 - Mc - Md <= x <= 4.999 + Mc + M(1-d)
c,d in {0,1}
x in [-M,M]
```

In practice we can often simplify this somewhat.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a boolean variable, that is not LP.  It is Integer Programming.

But if you have only one boolean variable `C`, you can solve two LP problems: with `C=1` and with `C=0`, then compare whose solution is better. I would suggest that.

Finally, the pair of conditions

```
C <= X / 5
C <= 5 / X
```

imposes very strange constraint on `C` if `X≠5`.